# What's the difference between is! and !is in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to see if a variable is not of a certain type. I know I can do `if(picture is XFile)`, but these both seem to work for the opposite:

`if(picture !is XFile)`

`if(picture is! XFile)`

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x !is T` is not what you think it is.  If you run `dart format` on your code, you'll see that it's actually `x! is T`; that is, it is using the *post-fix* `!` operator, which asserts that `x` is not `null`, and then performs a normal `is T` check (and therefore produces the opposite result than you expect).  If `x` is statically known to be non-nullable, `dart analyze` should generate a warning about using the null-assertion operator unnecessarily.

Perhaps you mean to compare `x is! T` and `!(x is T)`.  There is no logical difference between those expressions.  There is [a linter rule that suggests that `is!` should be preferred](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#prefer_is_not_operator), but it doesn't provide any explanation why.  I believe it's because `is!` ostensibly reads better ("is not") and is simpler than negating a parenthesized expression. (However, that stance predates null-safety, and arguably `is!` might be more confusing now that a post-fix `!` operator exists.)

Answer (score -2):

```dart
void main() {
  var myNum = 5;

  if (myNum is! int) {
    print('myNum is an integer');
  }else{
    print('not an integer');
  }
}
```

output : `not an integer` for the compiler it is same as `is !int`

```dart
void main() {
  var myNum = null;

  if (myNum is int) {
    print('myNum is an integer');
  }else{
    print('not an integer');
  }
}
```

output : `not an integer` because the value is `null` so is not an `int` makes sens

```dart
void main() {
  var myNum = null;

  if (myNum !is int) {
    print('myNum is an integer');
  }else{
    print('not an integer');
  }
}
```

output : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')` for the compiler it is same as `myNum! is` : the [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

it is like if `myNum` is `null` throw an `error` and do not check. Works as `is` if `myNum` is `not null`.

**CONCLUSION** :

> these both seem to work for the opposite : if(picture !is XFile) & if(picture is! XFile)

they should work for the opposite

Comment: This answer isn't wrong (and probably doesn't deserve the downvotes it's getting), but I think the way it's presented is a little confusing.

Comment: It looks clear for me, dont know

Comment: For example, both of your examples output "not an integer", which without a careful reading of your code could be misunderstood to indicate that they are equivalent.  It's not obvious that your second code snippet initialized `myVar` to something else.  I also didn't notice it before, but the remark about `is !int` is not correct. `!int` is nonsense. `is!` is its own operator.